# binding devexpress xtrareport EFdatasource at runtime

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, devexpress

I'm trying to bind a xtraReport-EFdatasource to a list, i have done this in designer mode quickly using the wizard, but i cant bind its datasource at runtime.

```
DataSource = Services.CoursesList();
```

I tryed this code in the report constructor, also in the XtraReport1_DataSourceDemanded event with no luck. the devexpress website show an example using bindingsource, but im using EFdatasource. Can you help me with a code sample please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer this - [How to use Entity Framework with Xtrareports](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q532435)

> The best way to accomplish your task is to place your Report class and
>   Entity objects into a separate class library. In this case, you will
>   be able to [bind the Report to a custom object at design time and
>   provide data at run time](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument7547).
>
> To pass data to your Report instance, handle the
>   [XtraReport.DataSourceDemanded event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_DataSourceDemandedtopic), create your Entity objects,
>   and pass them to the XtraReport.DataSource property.

**More References:**
[How to use the XtraReport with the Entity Framework](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q296708)